# How to test a custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

In my application home page, users can make a choice from a list using a form. 
The form collects the choice and sends it to a controller custom action whose only goal is to update the user's attribute `choice`:

```
<% form_tag({controller: "weekly_selections", action: "update_choice"}) do %>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :user_choice, book.title %></div>
    <%= submit_tag("choose", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm") %>
<% end %>
```

I created a `WeeklySelection` controller and a custom `update_choice` action:

```
class WeeklySelectionsController < ApplicationController

  def update_choice
    if current_user.choice_count < 10
      user_choice = params[:user_choice]
      current_user.update_attribute(:choice, user_choice)
      current_user.increment!(:choice_count)
      flash[:success] = 'Your choice has been recorded'
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Attention! You already made 10 choices"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

How can I test the correct behaviour of this action, or that the action actually works?

Comment: do you mean using a test suite like Rspec or just manually confirm the side effect of this action has occured?

Comment: I mean with an integration test.

Comment: what test framework are you looking to use? (Rspec, minitest/testunit)

Comment: I use minitest/testunit, the default framework